# Symfony2 Association class form

Tags: angularjs, forms, symfony, associations, model-associations

This is my first Symfony project, and I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

Basically, i'm trying to make an invoice using a form.

I have a "Facturation" (ie invoice) Entity, a "TypeOfService" Entity, and a "Service" Entity (the sole attribute of which is the quantity of the type of service needed for the invoice) that acts as an association class.

I'd like to dynamically add "New Service" fields to my FacturationType form using Javascript (probably AngularJS). So I have to create N new Service entities that each associate with both my Facturation entity and an existing TypeOfService entity.

Here's my Facturation entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * Facturation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="facturation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Facturation
{
    ...


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Service", mappedBy="facturation")
     */
    private $service;

    /**
     * Add service
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Service $service
     * @return Facturation
     */
    public function addService(\AppBundle\Entity\Service $service)
    {
        $this->service[] = $service;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove service
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Service $service
     */
    public function removeService(\AppBundle\Entity\Service $service)
    {
        $this->service->removeElement($service);
    }

    /**
     * Get service
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

}
```

Then Service:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * Service
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="service")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Service
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TypeOfService", inversedBy="service")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_of_service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $typeOfService;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Facturation", inversedBy="service")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="facturation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $facturation;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     * @return Service
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set typeOfService
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\TypeOfService $typeOfService
     * @return Service
     */
    public function setTypeOfService(\AppBundle\Entity\TypeOfService $typeOfService = null)
    {
        $this->typeOfService = $typeOfService;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typeOfService
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\TypeOfService 
     */
    public function getTypeOfService()
    {
        return $this->typeOfService;
    }

    /**
     * Set facturation
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Facturation $facturation
     * @return Service
     */
    public function setFacturation(\AppBundle\Entity\Facturation $facturation = null)
    {
        $this->facturation = $facturation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get facturation
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Facturation 
     */
    public function getFacturation()
    {
        return $this->facturation;
    }
}
```

And finally TypeOfService

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;


/**
 * TypeOfService
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type_of_service")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TypeOfService
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $pricePerUnit;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Service", mappedBy="typeOfService")
     */
    private $service;

    ...

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->service = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Add service
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Service $service
     * @return TypeOfService
     */
    public function addService(\AppBundle\Entity\Service $service)
    {
        $this->service[] = $service;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove service
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Service $service
     */
    public function removeService(\AppBundle\Entity\Service $service)
    {
        $this->service->removeElement($service);
    }

    /**
     * Get service
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->service;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, I've cracked it.

This was what I was looking for:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

This allows for dynamic field additions, using JS.
Be careful to cascade your association. In my case:

```
class Facturation
{
....
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Service", mappedBy="facturation", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $services;
```